# How to change Windows 10 interface language on Single Language version

Tags: windows-10, windows-mui

Unfortunately, on my PC was pre installed Windows 10 Single Language (BR Portuguese) and I can't change the "display language" from BR-PT to US English because don't have any options; for that obvious reason, indeed. So, please: how can I install a new "display language" onto Windows 10 Single Language version?

Comment: I got working instructions from here: http://www.howtogeek.com/232659/how-to-change-the-display-language-in-windows-10/     i had initially downloaded a portuguese version of windows 10.

Comment: @nyxee this doesn't work in Windows 10 Home SL, Only in Home or Pro

Comment: For a newer Windows builds I may recommend this article, worked for mine 21H2 19044.3086 perfectly: https://www.gaminghouse.community/en/guides-tutorials-1003/windows-10-change-language-on-single-language-system-137

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Worked for me:

1. Download package (see links below), name it lp.cab and place it to your `C:` drive
2. Run the following commands as Administrator:

2.1 installing new language

> dism /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:C:\lp.cab

2.2 get installed packages

> dism /Online /Get-Packages

2.3 remove original package

> dism /Online /Remove-Package
>   /PackageName:Microsoft-Windows-Client-LanguagePack-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~ru-RU~10.0.10240.16384

If you don't know which is your original package you can check your installed packages with this line

> dism /Online /Get-Packages | findstr /c:"LanguagePack"

3. Enjoy your new system language

List of MUI for Windows 10:

For LPs for Windows 10 version 1607 build 14393, follow [this](http://winaero.com/blog/mui-language-packs-for-windows-10-anniversary-update-rtm-version-1607-build-14393/) link.

**Windows 10 x64 (Build 10240)**:

zh-CN: Chinese download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_9949b0581789e2fc205f0eb005606ad1df12745b.cab

hr-HR: Croatian download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_c3bde55e2405874ec8eeaf6dc15a295c183b071f.cab

cs-CZ: Czech download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_d0b2a69faa33d1ea1edc0789fdbb581f5a35ce2d.cab

da-DK: Danish download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_15e50641cef50330959c89c2629de30ef8fd2ef6.cab

nl-NL: Dutch download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_8658b909525f49ab9f3ea9386a0914563ffc762d.cab

en-us: English download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_75d67444a5fc444dbef8ace5fed4cfa4fb3602f0.cab

fr-FR: French download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_206d29867210e84c4ea1ff4d2a2c3851b91b7274.cab

de-DE: German download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_3bb20dd5abc8df218b4146db73f21da05678cf44.cab

hi-IN: Hindi download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_e9deaa6a8d8f9dfab3cb90986d320ff24ab7431f.cab

it-IT: Italian download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_42c622dc6957875eab4be9d57f25e20e297227d1.cab

ja-JP: Japanese download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_adc2ec900dd1c5e94fc0dbd8e010f9baabae665f.cab

kk-KZ: Kazakh download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_a03ed475983edadd3eb73069c4873966c6b65daf.cab

ko-KR: Korean download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_24411100afa82ede1521337a07485c65d1a14c1d.cab

pt-BR: Portuguese download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_894199ed72fdf98e4564833f117380e45b31d19f.cab

ru-RU: Russian download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_d85bb9f00b5ee0b1ea3256b6e05c9ec4029398f0.cab

es-ES: Spanish download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_7b21648a1df6476b39e02476c2319d21fb708c7d.cab

uk-UA: Ukrainian download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_131991188afe0ef668d77c8a9a568cb71b57f09f.cab

**Windows 10 x86 (Build 10240)**:

zh-CN: Chinese download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_e7d13432345bcf589877cd3f0b0dad4479785f60.cab

hr-HR: Croatian download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_60856d8b4d643835b30d8524f467d4d352395204.cab

cs-CZ: Czech download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_dfa71b93a76b4500578b67fd3bf6b9f10bf5beaa.cab

da-DK: Danish download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_af0ea4318f43d9cb30bcfa5ce7279647f10bc3b3.cab

nl-NL: Dutch download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_cbcdf4818eac2a15cfda81e37595f8ffeb037fd7.cab

en-us: English download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_41877260829bb5f57a52d3310e326c6828d8ce8f.cab

fr-FR: French download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_80fa697f051a3a949258797a0635a4313a448c29.cab

de-DE: German download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_7ea2648033099f99f87642e47e6d959172c6cab8.cab

hi-IN: Hindi download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_78a11997f4e4bf73bbdb1da8011ebfb218bd1bac.cab

it-IT: Italian download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_9e62d9a8b141e0eb6434af5a44c4f9468b60a075.cab

ja-JP: Japanese download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_79bd099ac811cb1771e6d9b03d640e5eca636b23.cab

kk-KZ: Kazakh download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_59e690df497799cacb96ab579a706250e5a0c8b6.cab

ko-KR: Korean download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_a88379b0461479ab8b5b47f65c4c3241ef048c04.cab

pt-BR: Portuguese download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_bb9f192068fe42fde8787591197a53c174dce880.cab

ru-RU: Russian download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_280bf97bbe34cec1b0da620fa1b2dfe5bdb3ea07.cab

es-ES: Spanish download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_31400c38ffea2f0a44bb2dfbd80086aa3cad54a9.cab

uk-UA: Ukrainian download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/07/lp_41cd48aa22d21f09fbcedc69197609c1f05f433d.cab

Comment: The removing of the package takes very long, but it works.

Comment: I got Error: 0x800f081e while trying to add...I upgraded from a Windows 7 Professional single language where it was not possible to change to English http://superuser.com/questions/331779/how-can-i-change-the-language-of-windows-7-to-english

Comment: I solved by using the language packs for 10586, these are for 10240...

Comment: how to download language packs for different version (14393). i tried this and got trouble. repaired pc, back to chinese again.

Comment: i got that link from the google search 14393 windows langauge pack

Comment: @AlbertoRivelli in case anyone is wondering for the 10586 version of language pack, here's the link: **x86**: http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/11/lp_884bf1d8230c008e30bf4c2d06d1077c0ef6adb5.cab. **x64**: http://download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/11/lp_cde3e6fcf3e36d655948c41fc1dd847c09f7d23f.cab

Comment: This is a great solution. I had an issue where the default language (Russian) was persisting even after installing en-US and changing the language pack. After removing the russian language pack and restarting, the system defaulted to english. Thank you!

Comment: Warning: I got MUI_NO_VALID_SYSTEM_LANGUAGE error after reboot, and was unable to restore to a recovery point. Factory reset (which erased everything) worked though. I'm using 1607 build 14393.

Comment: This worked great on Fall Creators Update

Comment: Where can I find a link for 16299?

Comment: @Bassie Hello, could you please describe in more details how did you remove russian language?

Comment: Windows 10 v.1803 (17134.1) links? Thanks

Comment: got MUI_NO_VALID_SYSTEM_LANGUAGE too.version 1709 build 16299.15

Comment: Is there a .cab for Win 10, v1803?

Comment: I have found language packs for 1803 [here](https://www.itechtics.com/download-language-packs-windows-10-version-1803/)

Comment: I'm getting `The specified package is not applicable to this image.`.
Dism version: `Version: 10.0.17134.1`
Pack from @VasilyTomilchik 's link `Image Version: 10.0.17134.472`

Comment: WARNING: This causes MUI_NO_VALID_SYSTEM_LANGUAGE under Windows 10 Home Edition. The Home Edition is limited to its original language pack. If you remove the original language pack, Windows does not start.

Comment: For windows 10 build 1803 update 17134 download links:
https://www.tobias-hartmann.net/2018/05/windows-10-language-packs-1803-build-17134-april-2018-update-download/

Comment: It worked for me to change the system language. But didn't solve my problem which occurs in Turkish workstations (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7315) So I guess I make a clean install in English..

Comment: any link for 1903 ?

Comment: @Damien did you find a 1903 link? I'm also looking for it.

Comment: Go to uupdump.ml and search for your windows build version (1903). Look for "Cumulative Updates" of your windows version. In "Search Files", enter "languagepack". You will get *.esd files. Click on "Generate Renaming Script". Then download desired *.esd file/files. Keep them under same folder. Rename and run the script. Get *.cab using https://github.com/abbodi1406/WHD/blob/master/scripts/ESD2CAB-CAB2ESD.zip Further info - https://www.ntlite.com/community/index.php?threads/language-pack-downloads-windows-10-8-1-7.17/page-4

Comment: No need to delete other language pack. After step 2.1, go to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language** on regedit.
Then change **Default** to desire (and installed of course) language id, then restart computer. To see desired language ids, check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx)

Comment: @Mark 's solution worked in my case (build version 1909). follow the instructions in the readme file inside the tool from Github: [link](https://github.com/abbodi1406/WHD/blob/master/scripts/ESD2CAB-CAB2ESD.zip) 
it converts simple ESD files to CAB files and vice versa, after that edit the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language default keys as mentioned in tatoline's answer. thanks to you all!

Comment: Thanks @IsmailYavuz, I tried to update the link in the answer back in 2018 but was told it was "superfluous" and "deviates from the intent of the answer".

Comment: I tried this to switch from `nl-nl` to `us-en`, but found out that after this the `RefreshWindowsTool.exe` to get Windows back to a clean state indicates it is not supported on the locale. I will fiddle with this a bit more during the next few days, to ensure it isn't a thing I goofed up at.

Link for the refresh tool: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_repair/now-available-start-fresh-with-a-clean-install-of/55a2f3c7-4795-4685-b3ee-20187684c511 and https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10startfresh

Answer (score 8):

You can download language pack and use "Install or Uninstall display languages" wizard. To do this:

- Press `Win+R`, paste `lpksetup` and press `Enter`
- Wizard will appear on the screen
- Click the `Install display languages` button
- In the next page of the wizard, click `Browse` and pick the *.cab file of the MUI language you downloaded
- Click the Next button to install language

Comment: With Windows 10 Single Language Home I get a warning message when selecting the .cab file saying Windows cannot install additional language packs. See Note in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748922%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 5):

Actually, it looks like you may be able to download language packs directly through Windows Update. Open the old Control Panel by pressing WinKey+X and clicking Control Panel. Then go to Clock, Language, and Region > Add a language. Add the desired language. Then under the language it should say "Windows display language: Available". Click "Options" and then "Download and install language pack."

I'm not sure why this functionality appears to be less accessible than it was in Windows 8.

Comment: Unavailable in Windows 10. At least not in my build (14393).

Answer (score 3):

1) Upgrade using windows update or using "media creation tool"
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install

- if you are using "media creation tool" select "Upgrade this PC now"

When Windows 10 installed check that it is activated.

2) Now as you have activated Windows 10 using "media creation tool"
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install select second option "Create installation media for another PC" here you can select Windows version and its language. Make sure that Windows version is also "Single Language"

3) Boot from you device, USB in my case and install clean Windows in English or any other language you selected.

reference http://bit.ly/1RKmPBs

Comment: The last reference link is broken.

Comment: Thanks updated link.

Comment: Better option **without install clean Windows**, go to [How to Change Language of Windows 10 Single Language Without Format](https://superuser.com/questions/1537466/how-to-change-language-of-windows-10-single-language-without-format/1537486#1537486)